# Closure vs Derived set in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X\subset \mathbb R$ a subset and $a\in \mathbb R$.

> **i)** We say $a$ is an **adherent point** of $X$ if $X\cap
> (a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)\neq \emptyset$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.
>   The set of all adherent points of $X$, denoted by $\overline{X}$, is
>   called the **closure** of $X$.

There is a similar notion:

> **ii)** We say $a$ is a **limit point** of $X$ if $X\cap ((a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)-\{a\})\neq \emptyset $ for every
>   $\varepsilon>0$. The set of all limit points of $X$, denoted by
>   $X^\prime$, is called the **derived set** of $X$.

From the definition it is clear that:

$$X\subset \overline{X}\quad \textrm{and}\quad X^\prime\subset \overline{X}.$$ Indeed, it holds $$\overline{X}=X^\prime\cup X.$$

> **Question 1.** Can anyone provide me examples where $\overline{X}\neq X^\prime$?

I thought of the following:

- $X=(0, 1)\cup \{2\}$. Then $X^\prime=[0, 1]$ and $\overline{X}=[0, 1]\cup \{2\}$. In particular, $X^\prime$ does not contain $X$.
- If $F\neq \emptyset $ is discrete then $F^\prime=\emptyset $ and $\overline{F}=F\neq F^\prime$.

Furtheremore, I know that $$(X\cup Y)^\prime=X^\prime\cup Y^\prime, \quad\overline{X\cup Y}=\overline{X}\cup \overline{Y}\quad \textrm{and}\quad  \overline{X\cap Y} \subset \overline{X}\cap \overline{Y}.$$

> **Question 2**. What is the relationship between $(X\cap Y)^\prime$ and $X^\prime\cap Y^\prime$?

Finally:

> **Question 3.** Are there other interesting properties of the derived set?

I already know that:

- $X$ is closed if and only if $X^\prime\subset X$;
- If $X^\prime\neq \emptyset $ then $X$ is infinite.

Thanks.

Comment: Another example is $Y = \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \right\}$. Then $Y' = \{0\}$ and $\overline{Y} = Y \cup \{0\}$.

Comment: Doesn't the comment of @LucyYang show that in fact $X'$ needn't be infinite just because it isn't empty?

Comment: Hint for question 2: Observe that if $X \subseteq Y$, then $X' \subseteq Y'$. What can you deduce from $X \cap Y \subseteq X, Y$? Note that the reverse inclusion needn't hold: find $X' \cap Y'$ and $(X \cap Y)'$ when $X = \left\{\frac{1}{2n} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \right\}$ and $Y = \left\{  \frac{1}{2n +1} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \right\}$

Comment: @MPW my statement was $X^\prime\neq \phi\Rightarrow X$ is infinite and not $X^\prime\neq \phi\Rightarrow X^\prime$ is infinite. In Lucy Yang example, $Y$ is infinite..

Comment: @LucyYang $(X\cap Y)^\prime=\phi$ since $X\cap Y=\phi$ and $X^\prime\cap Y^\prime=\{0\}$, right? Thanks for the example =)

Comment: @PtF : Ah, I see. I have misread your observation.Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @MPW You're welcome =)

Answer (score 1):

1. $\overline {\{x\}}\neq  \{x\}^\prime$;
2. As $A \subseteq B$ implies $A^\prime \subseteq B^\prime$,
   $(A' \cap B') \subseteq A' \cap B'.$
3. Limit points are a nusiance, of no use topologically except for scattered spaces (a minor topic), and a terrible way to define the closure of a set.  $A = \{ 1/n : n\in \mathbb N \}$ is a scattered space of scattering height two;  namely $A^{\prime\prime}=\emptyset$ but $A^\prime\neq \emptyset$.  Every ordinal is scattered.  A discrete space is scattered.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As to your first example, it adds nothing new since $\{x\}\neq \phi$ is discrete and I had pointed out in my question that any non-empty discrete set $F$ satisfies $F^\prime\neq \overline{F}$. As to scattered spaces, I've never heard about, can you give me any reference?

Comment: @PtF  A web search yields some stuff.  Wikipedia for example.